# Error checking Integer division by zero

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arguments

I am writing a base conversion program in C++ console and I am using argv[1] and argv[2] for 
entering the number & base.

```
     #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
  #include <time.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <errno.h> 
 using namespace std;
const double MAXRANGE = pow(2.0,16.0); // 65536
 const double MINRANGE = -pow(2.0,16.0);

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

int result;

if(atof (argv[1]) > 65536)
 { 
cout << "R" << endl;
return 0;
   }

   if(atof (argv[1]) < -65536)
    { 
 cout << "R" << end;
 return 0;
    }


    if(atof (argv[2]) > 65536 || (atof(argv[2]) < -65536))
   { 
cout << "R" << endl;
return 0;
     }


    int no,base,i;
   no=atoi(argv[1]);
   base=atoi(argv[2]);


      if (argc == 3 )
        {
   if(argv[2][0]=='b' && argv[2][1]=='2')
   {  
       cout<<"V"<<endl;

        return 0;
         }

       i= no % base;
        no=no/base;
        cout<<i;

                }

           return (0); 
             }
```

and I got the error which is

**Unhandled exception at 0x012851BE in lab1.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.**

I understand this error is coming up because I have make condition with zero.But I am not sure, the sure thing is that i don't know how to do error checking now.
I have also tried another code

```
            if(strcmp("b2",argv[2]==0 || strcmp("b3",argv[2]==0)
```

but it still come up with the same error.

So, How can I do error checking for argv[2] base numbers? The user have to input argv[2] which is base, and I want to check the argv[2] must be 'b1','b2', 'b3' etc.. to 'b16'.

thank you!

Comment: It's `base` that you're dividing by, not the irrelevant 0 in the `strcmp` equality check.

Comment: @chris yes,i can understand the error but how can i approach  to error check!thx!

Comment: What would you expect base to be after this call `base=atoi(argv[2])` when `argv[2] == "b2"`?  Hint, that isn't a valid string to pass to `atoi`.

Comment: yes! I kinda get that I can't make int and then string again.is there any other way to check argv[2]! thanks @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check base against zero prior to the corresponding division or throwm catch and handle your zero division exception, i.e.:

```
if (!base) {
    ...
    // or early return depending on your use case
} else {
   i = no % base;
   no=no/base;
}
```

or:

```
   try {
       ...
       if (!base)
           throw std::overflow_error("Divide by zero exception");
       i = no % base;
       no=no/base;
   } catch (std::overflow_error e) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: I kinda get it but as you see my code is simple. I am just a beginner, can you show me how to do error checking on argv[2] by using if statement? thx! :)

Comment: Why would you check argv[2] when the zero is base? Are you initializing base somewhere to argv[2] in some unshown code?

Comment: yes! sorry, the user have to input 'b1', 'b2' etc for base in command line. so I need to check for valid input 'b1','b2'..etc..

Comment: @SbSangpi "... as you see...", No, actually, we don't see. Your code as presented doesn't even *compile*. Include a working (in this case failing) **runnable** `main()` along with the *exact* command line parameters presented to the process at launch.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question again, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @SbSangpi: so what is wrong with my answer? It is comparisong base against zero already?

Comment: Why would it check when it is a number? Also, you are getting zero divison error which is fixed by my answer.

Comment: Division by zero doesn't throw an exception, it's undefined behaviour. Thus, the second won't work.